# Парсинг фото и подписи фото в телеграм боте на Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Пользователь отправляет боту фотографию(только что сделанную через телеграмм) с подписью к ней.
Нужно получить file_id и caption, что бы потом использовать в другом месте.
Я только начал и это трудно для понимания, целый день гуглю не могу разобраться, помогите пожалуйста :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
async def handler(message):
    file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
    caption = message.caption
```